# Русификатор программы Pure Basic 5.11 работает неправильно

Tags: visual-basic

[image: Скриншот запуска программы]

Что сделать, чтобы вместо "?????" было "АБВГД" ? Подскажите что-нибудь, пожалуйста, в интернете поискал - ни у кого такой проблемы вроде как нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Недавно нашёл ответ на свой вопрос.
Необходимо выполнить следующие действия: `Файл` > `Формат файла` > `Кодировка: Простой текст` отметить галочку. Затем все открытые файлы сохранить повторно, и со следующим запуском программы всё будет работать стабильно.

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте что у вас в системе по умолчанию стоит русский язык для не-Unicode программ. Без этого в старых программах будут вопросы вместо русских букв:

Настройка находится в `Панель управления` > `Часы, язык и регион` > `Язык и региональные стандарты` > `Дополнительно` > `Язык программ, не поддерживающих Юникод`. Выберите там русский и перезагрузитесь.